# How to show$\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot6\cdot6\cdot8 \dotsm}{3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7\cdot7 \dotsm}$?

Tags: approximation, pi, infinite-product

I am doing the exercises of [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3). In exercise 1.31 the following equation is casually shown as an approximation of $\pi$:

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot6\cdot6\cdot8 \dotsm}{3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7\cdot7 \dotsm}$$

How can this possibly be? Can someone provide me with more information on this approximation?

Comment: Look up Wallis Product.

Comment: [See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product)

Comment: Thanks! Remains a very strange fact that pi can be approximated like that. I am spacing out while trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @user2609980 another cool one is $$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\ldots$$

Comment: @graydad What is the derivation for that one?

Comment: @user2609980 It comes from the Taylor Series of $$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ Plug in $x = 1$ to get the result.

Comment: @user2609980 Also, the brilliant mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan was famous for finding things like $$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^4 396^{4k}}.$$